# HERE API: Doesn't recognize appId and appCode as parameters in React

Tags: reactjs, here-api, heremaps

Error: H.service.Platform (Argument #0 "apikey" must be specified)
InvalidArgumentError: H.service.Platform (Argument #0 "apikey" must be specified)

My HERE Maps setup does not include an apikey as one of the validating fields. Is there any way to work around this by using appId and appCode instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HERE provides support for two types of credentials to access services: API Key and OAuth 2.0 token credentials. Legacy APPCODE credentials are no longer supported. See [HERE IAM Developer Guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/here-platform.html) for more information. In your case, API Key is likely the right type to use. Please check the case for your apikey parameter - some services may require camel case (apiKey).

*Disclaimer: I am a product manager at HERE Technologies*